# PHP mail() ' (single quote) in subject being escaped

Tags: php, html-email

I am trying to send emails using php `mail()` function. My code is below.

```
$subject = "Let's Connect";
$to = $_POST['to'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail( $to, $subject, $message, array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'));
```

The problem is `'` in the subject line becomes `\'` in email clients such as Gmail and Yahoo. The `Let's Connect` becomes `Let\'s Connect`. I have tried several solutions here, like

`$sub = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';`
`$decoded_str = html_entity_decode (  $value_to_decode, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' );`

None of them seems to work. What should I do to get it solved?

Thaks

Comment: Did you tried double quotes? `$subject = "Let's Connect";`

Comment: @SananGuliyev Yes, I am using double quote. Mistakenly entered single quote while typing this question.

Comment: Have you tried changing your `$subject` variable to `$subject = "Let\'s Connect";` do you still get the same thing happen on the email?

Comment: I guess found solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `stripslashes()` and `html_entity_decode()`

```
mail( $to, stripslashes(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' )), $message, array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'));
```

Comment: I would not use double quotes in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 1):

Either use double quotes like this:

```
$subject = "Let's Connect";
```

Or you can use slash to skip it

```
$subject = 'Let\'s Connect';
```

You can pass `stripslashes($subject)`

Comment: My bad, yes, I was using double quotes in my development code. Mistakenly used single quote while typing this question. Edited my question.